# How to select a single row a 100 million x

Tags: mysql

I would like to generate the following output, using a single row from a select.

```
SELECT max(t1.id)+1 as new_id FROM t1;
-> 101

However I want to do

SELECT s.last_id, sequence(1..100000000) as new_id 
FROM (SELECT max(table1.id)+1 as last_id FROM table1) s;
-> 101,1
-> 101,2
-> 101,3 
......
-> 101,100000000
```

In postgreSQL I can do this using:

```
SELECT s.last_id, generate_series(1,100000000) 
FROM (SELECT max(table1.id)+1 as last_id FROM table1) s;  -- returns 100,000,000 rows
```

How do I do this in **MySQL** without using a temp-table?

Comment: What about derived tables? Also can we assume the existence of an arbitrary table with at least 100 rows?

Comment: @MartinSmith, Clever, I would prefer a solution without that assumption, so NO all tables have just 1 row in them.

Comment: @Johan: If all your tables have 1 row in them, you don't need a db, do you?

Comment: @ypercube, I tagged it with `trick` because I need to use this trick to populate the DB with random data fast. Would you like me to write a 100 million rows?

Comment: I was just teasing you. But yeah, mentioning that you want this to be used with very large sequences, would be good.

Comment: With the `without a temp table` restriction, I would use a `cross join` on derived tables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Slight amend to Bruno's solution

```
SELECT (SELECT COALESCE(max(id),0)+1 FROM table1), 
        @rownum:=@rownum+1 new_id 
FROM 
(SELECT @rownum:=0) r, 
(SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2) t1,
(SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2) t2,
(SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2) t3,
(SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2) t4,
(SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2) t5,
(SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2) t6,
(SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2) t7
LIMIT 100
```

Or another version without the variables

```
SELECT (SELECT Coalesce(MAX(id), 0) + 1
        FROM   table1),
       t1.n * 10 + t2.n + 1 AS new_id
FROM   (SELECT 0 AS n UNION ALL
        SELECT 1      UNION ALL
        SELECT 2      UNION ALL
        SELECT 3      UNION ALL
        SELECT 4      UNION ALL
        SELECT 5      UNION ALL
        SELECT 6      UNION ALL
        SELECT 7      UNION ALL
        SELECT 8      UNION ALL
        SELECT 9) t1,
       (SELECT 0 AS n UNION ALL
        SELECT 1      UNION ALL
        SELECT 2      UNION ALL
        SELECT 3      UNION ALL
        SELECT 4      UNION ALL
        SELECT 5      UNION ALL
        SELECT 6      UNION ALL
        SELECT 7      UNION ALL
        SELECT 8      UNION ALL
        SELECT 9) t2
ORDER  BY new_id
```

Comment: I think if you replace the `limit` with a `where` it will run even faster. Great answer, because you don't need to pre-create a number generator.

Comment: Just one question if I may, can I expand this to 100,000,000 rows?

Comment: @Johan - You could stick it into a View and cross join multiple times. If you did the multiple cross join trick in separate views it would only need 3 views for `10`, `100`, `10,000` then cross join on the last one to get `100,000,000`

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @harper89 I found the answer here:

http://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2011-07-30/mysql-row-generator#mysql_generator_code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW generator_16
AS SELECT 0 n UNION ALL SELECT 1  UNION ALL SELECT 2  UNION ALL 
   SELECT 3   UNION ALL SELECT 4  UNION ALL SELECT 5  UNION ALL
   SELECT 6   UNION ALL SELECT 7  UNION ALL SELECT 8  UNION ALL
   SELECT 9   UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL
   SELECT 12  UNION ALL SELECT 13 UNION ALL SELECT 14 UNION ALL 
   SELECT 15;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW generator_256
AS SELECT ( ( hi.n << 4 ) | lo.n ) AS n
     FROM generator_16 
     CROSS JOIN generator_16 hi;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW generator_4k
AS SELECT ( ( hi.n << 8 ) | lo.n ) AS n
     FROM generator_256 lo
     CROSS JOIN generator_16 hi;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW generator_64k
AS SELECT ( ( hi.n << 8 ) | lo.n ) AS n
     FROM generator_256 lo
     CROSS JOIN generator_256 hi;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW generator_1m
AS SELECT ( ( hi.n << 16 ) | lo.n ) AS n
     FROM generator_64k lo
     CROSS JOIN generator_16 hi;
```

Now I can generate the result I want using:

```
SELECT s.last_id, g.n as new_id FROM (SELECT max(table1.id)+1 as last_id FROM table1) s
CROSS JOIN generator_256 g
WHERE G.N BETWEEN 1 AND 100
ORDER BY g.n ASC;
```

Using `LIMIT` is a bad idea, because than up to a million+ rows will be stored in a temp-table. With the `where` you don't need the temp-storage.

Comment: Ah, I was lamenting the lack of CTEs in MySQL but of course you can just use a view (+1) not familiar enough with MySQL to know the downsides of `LIMIT`!

Comment: @MartinSmith, Limit works by just selecting all rows, storing those in a temp table (on disk or in mem) and only feeding you the first x rows.

Comment: Well my second version doesn't need either. BTW Every positive integer is the sum of some powers of 2 so maybe you could create views for every power of 2 up till some number then cross join on a union all that adds up to the correct number? Or would that get materialised into some intermediate result set in MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in MYSql that is equal to `generate_series`. And after reading the below link it seems everything SQL does except MySQL.

Confirmed [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701444/how-do-i-make-a-row-generator-in-mysql)

It seems you will have to take a more complicated route, but I am not experienced enough to give an answer, the link and answers there may lead you in the right directiom.

**Side Note:**

You can use `LIMIT 100` to only return 100 rows, but it seems you want something slightly different.

Comment: +1, that link is golden. The solution is at the bottom of the article.

Comment: Awesome, I wasn't sure I only knew that generate wasn't an option. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Johan,

You use this form:

```
SELECT max(t1.id)+1, @rownum:=@rownum+1 rownum
FROM (SELECT @rownum:=0) r, t1;
```

Test this sql I think the code was resolve.

Comment: You're missing a `LIMIT` but `max(t1.id)+1` will only return 1 row anyway so you need to expand this result somehow.

Comment: You are doing a cross join on two resultsets with just one row each. That will just generate 1 row. I feel you are moving in the right direction, but this is not it.